# MIPS architecture R-type explanation

Tags: assembly, mips

i try to learn the MIPS architecture and i kind of stuck
at the R-Type instruction set.
i know that in MIPS there is 32 registers
each can old 32 bits data.
but in R-type the rs rt and rd fields only 5 bits long.
so what if i  want to do something like
add $t0, 4000, 5000?
how that instruction is going to fit in R-TYPE or even bigger numbers
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There are no ALU instructions to add two constants. You can either add two registers or a register and a constant.

This is what you can do:

```
li $t0, 4000
addiu $t0, $t0, 5000
```

or

```
li $t0, 4000
li $t1, 5000
addu $t0, $t0, $t1
```